# Convert file system format on AWS EC2 ephemeral storage disk from ext3 to ext4

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an instance-store EC2 instance with Ubuntu 11.04 i386. At present my disk partition looks like this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            9.9G  529M  8.9G   6% /
none                  828M  116K  828M   1% /dev
none                  833M     0  833M   0% /dev/shm
none                  833M   40K  833M   1% /var/run
none                  833M     0  833M   0% /var/lock
/dev/xvda2            147G  188M  140G   1% /mnt
```

Can I convert /mnt (/dev/xvda2) to ext4? If yes, can you please guide me or point me to the right resource.

Thanks

Comment: What filesystem is it right now? Do a `cat /etc/mtab` to find out.

Comment: At present its ext3 - /dev/xvda2 /mnt ext3 rw 0 0

Comment: Then just edit `/etc/fstab` and change ext3 to ext4. That's all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert `/mnt` from ext3 to ext4 in place (after backing up data for safety):

```
dev=/dev/xvda2
sudo umount $dev
sudo tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index $dev
sudo fsck -fv $dev
sudo mount $dev
```

You don't have to edit `/etc/fstab` on Ubuntu 11.04 for EC2 since the AMI lists that file system as `auto`.

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ConvertFilesystemToExt4

Answer (score 3):

1. Backup /mnt/
2. `umount /mnt/`
3. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvda2`
4. `mount /mnt/`
5. Restore your files

Comment: Thanks it works. Even mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvda2 works fine.